# Custom attributes return null when logged in angular 2

Tags: angular

```
template
<button type="button"
        (click)="leaderBoard($event)"
        attr.leaders = "individual"
        [class.active]="individualLeaderboard">
   <label>INDIVIDUALS</label>
</button>
<button type="button"
        (click)="leaderBoard($event)"
         attr.leaders = "team"
         [class.active]="teamLeaderboard">
   <label>TEAMS</label>
```

```
.ts File

leaderBoard($event) {
    console.log($event.target.getAttribute('attr.leaders'))
 }
```

I'm simply trying to log the value of the custom attribute when each element is clicked.  It works fine if I only have one button, but returns null if there are multiple buttons. Can someone explain the issue to me?

Comment: can you replicate a plunker

Comment: What is your "leaderBoard" attribute supposed to be exactly? Because you didn't give your buttons such an attribute in the code you provided us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to:

```
<button type="button" (click)="leaderBoard($event)"
 leaders='individual' 
 [class.active]="individualLeaderboard">
 <label>INDIVIDUALS</label> 
</button>
```

.. and in your ts:

```
leaderBoard($event){
console.log($event.currentTarget.getAttribute('leaders'));
 }
```

Comment: Plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/1SEPrtw8foSeDVSwvhmM?p=preview (ignore the extra code)

Answer (score 0):

Would you replace your ts code with:

```
leaderBoard($event) {
    console.log($event.target.getAttribute('attr.leaders'));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I was copying the code over.  The function still returns null.